# Difference between two fields in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have searched the web for (what I am expecting to be) a basic answer to this question.

I have an HTML form I am putting together for a specific system. I have two text fields that a user will input two temperatures into. I want to have a third text field that onBlur, will generate the difference between these two temperatures. I have a script which I think is heading in the right direction, but does not work. Because of the system I will be using this for, I cannot have  tags in the HTML.

My script:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function calculate_temp(TempIn, TempOut) {
    var TempIn = parseInt(document.getElementById('TempIn').value);
    var TempOut   = parseInt(document.getElementById('TempOut').value); 
    var Delta = TempIn - TempOut;
    document.getElementById('Delta').innerHTML = Delta
    }
    // -->
    </script>
```

My HTML:

```
    <body> 
    <div> 
    <p><label for="TempIn">TempIn: </label><input type="text" name="TempIn" id="TempIn" /></p>
    <p><label for="TempOut">TempOut: </label><input type="text" name="TempOut" id="TempOut" /></p>
    <p><label for="Delta">Delta: </label> <input type="text" name="Delta" id="Delta" onBlur="calculate_temp(this.form.TempIn.value, this.form.TempOut.value)"/></p>
    </div> 
    </body>
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here? Again, I want the user to input TempIn, hit tab, input TempOut, hit tab and then the Delta be calculated automatically.

Like I said, every resource I find online does it a slightly different way, but I can't seem to get it working if I use any of the approaches.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try `document.getElementById('Delta').value = Delta;` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Why are you passing TempIn and TempOut as argument when you are retrieving them in script function?

Comment: Using onfocus instead of onblur might be helpful!

Comment: @Treb If you take a look at OP's profile, he has been a member for over a year and has 13 questions. But I guess it's possible that noone ever told him how to accept answers before though. EDIT: never mind, he commented on James Montagne's answer.

Comment: @Fabricio: My bad, I should have checked his profile. Michael and Zero21xxx, I apologize, your comments were justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the comments in your script: .
2. All tags and attribute names must be lowercase in XHTML (optional). i.e:
   onblur.
3. For your expected behavior, I recommend use the `onfocus` event,
   it makes more sense.
4. You don't need to pass nothing to the calculate_temp() function if
   you can access the elements through the script.
5. Change the value of the `Delta` input with the `value` property.

Result:

```
<head>

<title>Untitled 1</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function calculate_temp(TempIn, TempOut) {
            var TempIn = parseInt(document.getElementById('TempIn').value);
            var TempOut   = parseInt(document.getElementById('TempOut').value); 
            var Delta = TempIn - TempOut;
            document.getElementById('Delta').value = Delta
        }   
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div> 
    <p><label for="TempIn">TempIn: </label><input type="text" name="TempIn" id="TempIn" /></p>
    <p><label for="TempOut">TempOut: </label><input type="text" name="TempOut" id="TempOut" /></p>
    <p><label for="Delta">Delta: </label> <input type="text" name="Delta" id="Delta" onfocus="calculate_temp()"/></p>
    </div> 

</body>
```

Comment: Yes! Awesome.. thank you so much!! Any my apologies everyone. Yes, I have been here for a year, but didn't know proper etiquette on marking correct answers. Never really had a truly correct answer before. Just marked this one, thank you for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

An `input` doesn't have an `innerHTML`, you should use value.

```
document.getElementById('Delta').value = Delta
```

Also, **always** pass the 2nd parameter to `parseInt` which is the radix.  Otherwise it will often guess the wrong radix.

Comment: I promise to accept if I get an answer that works :p I don't think I have ever had an answer successfully answered here!

EDIT: Just accepted two answers, all my other questions weren't responded to.. sorry! I'm still new to how all of this works.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat in the ring....

html:

```
    <div> 
        <p><label for="TempIn">TempIn: </label><input type="text" name="TempIn" id="TempIn"/></p>
        <p><label for="TempOut">TempOut: </label><input type="text" name="TempOut" id="TempOut" /></p>
        <p><label for="Delta">Delta: </label> <input type="text" name="Delta" id="Delta"/></p>
    </div> ​​​​
```

js:

```
/* store elements */
var TempIn = document.getElementById('TempIn'),
    TempOut = document.getElementById('TempOut'),
    Delta = document.getElementById('Delta');

function calculate_temp() {
    Delta.value = parseInt(TempIn.value,10) - parseInt(TempOut.value,10);
}

/* unobtrusive onblur */
TempIn.onblur = calculate_temp;
TempOut.onblur = calculate_temp;
Delta.onblur = calculate_temp;
```

​here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/TbHW3/

**EDIT** should probably mention, this JS should be right above your `</body>` tag, or be run when the dom has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnBlur`event fires when the control in question looses the focus, so your code can only get called, when the user moves the focus away from the `Delta` input. You want it to get called when the `TempOut` input looses it's focus,  so that's where your event handling should be setup:

```
<p><label for="TempIn">TempIn: </label><input type="text" name="TempIn" id="TempIn" /></p>
<p><label for="TempOut">TempOut: </label><input type="text" name="TempOut" id="TempOut" onBlur="calculate_temp(this.form.TempIn.value, this.form.TempOut.value)"/></p>
<p><label for="Delta">Delta: </label> <input type="text" name="Delta" id="Delta" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function calculate_temp() {
var TempIn = parseInt(document.getElementById('TempIn').value);
var TempOut   = parseInt(document.getElementById('TempOut').value); 
var Delta = TempIn - TempOut;
document.getElementById('Delta').value = Delta;
}
// -->
</script>
```

html:

```
<body> 
<div> 
<p><label for="TempIn">TempIn: </label><input type="text" name="TempIn" id="TempIn" /></p>
<p><label for="TempOut">TempOut: </label><input type="text" name="TempOut" id="TempOut" /></p>
<p><label for="Delta">Delta: </label> <input type="text" name="Delta" id="Delta" onBlur="calculate_temp()"/></p>
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div> 
        <p><label for="TempIn">TempIn: </label><input type="text" name="TempIn" id="TempIn" onBlur="calculate_temp(document.getElementById('TempIn').value, document.getElementById('TempOut').value);"/></p>
        <p><label for="TempOut">TempOut: </label><input type="text" name="TempOut" id="TempOut" onBlur="calculate_temp(document.getElementById('TempIn').value, document.getElementById('TempOut').value);"/></p>
        <p><label for="Delta">Delta: </label> <input type="text" name="Delta" id="Delta" /></p>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function calculate_temp(TempIn, TempOut) {

        var Delta = TempIn - TempOut;
        document.getElementById('Delta').value = Delta
        }
    // -->
    </script>
```